# Codeigniter session concept brief explanation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Explain codeigniter session conpect.
I can not understand,Help me.

```
  <?php

     $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
     echo $this->session->set_userdata($array);

  ?>
```

Comment: I guess [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) guides tells you more than enough

Comment: Did you read the official documentation ? [https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: @huggilou http://www.codeigniter.com/docs new location now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with an application, you open it, do some changes, and then you close it. This is much like a Session. The computer knows who you are. It knows when you start the application and when you end. But on the internet there is one problem: the web server does not know who you are or what you do, because the HTTP address doesn't maintain state.

Session variables solve this problem by storing user information to be used across multiple pages (e.g. username, favorite color, etc). By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.

So; Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

setting the session data,

```
  $patientRegId  = $this->uri->segment(3);

  $this->session->set_userdata("SESSION_REG_ID",$patientRegId);
```

availing the session data,

```
  $patientRegId = $this->session->userdata("SESSION_REG_ID");
```

Comment: hi Madhu, I got you one question: i'm saving an array into a session, then I make some Paypal payments and the when it come back and get the sessions userdata, it's without that info I saved. Pretty weird, what cloud happen? the data is less than 4kb if you wonder that

Comment: @BraianMellor, were you able to solve your issue? We have a similar issue in [CodeIgniter 3.1.11 with PHP 7.2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265088/session-not-working-in-codeigniter-3-x-and-php7-2-x)

Comment: @KrishnaChebrolu I don't remember it was 4 years ago

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION in core php is equivalent to $this->session->all_userdata().
In codeigniter bydefault some data like 
`[session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
    [last_activity] => 1303142623`

are added to session .

For adding item in to session , you need to `use$this->session->set_userdata('id' , '3');`

In core php , `$_SESSION['id'] = 3;`

If you want to store multiple items on session , you may directly store an array containing keys and values that needs to be stored in session .
ex: `$array = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($array);`

I hope you understood the concept of session in code igniter.

Thanks ,

Lakin